# NE-Lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ with $k$ peaks

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $n$ and $k$ be natural numbers. I will consider [North-East lattice paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_path#North-East_lattice_paths) (NE-paths) from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ and encode these as strings of length $2n$ with letters $\mathsf{N}$ and $\mathsf{E}$. A *peak* of such a lattice path $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{x_1x_2\dots x_{2n}}$ is an index $i$ such that $\mathsf{x_i x_{i+1}}=\mathsf{NE}$. The *major index* of $P$ is the sum of the peaks of $\mathsf{P}$. As an example, the NE-path $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{ENNENEEENENN}$ has peaks at indices $3,5$ and $9$ and hence $\text{maj}(\mathsf{P})=3+5+9=17$. I have two questions regarding these paths.

1. From [this](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C4%2C1%2C1%2C9%2C9%2C1&sort=&language=&go=Search) OEIS-entry, I understand that the number NE-paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ with exactly $k$ peaks is equal to $\binom{n}{k}^2$. Does someone know a proof or a reference for this?
2. I suspect that the $\text{maj}$-generating polynomial over this set of paths has the following nice closed form expression:
   $$\sum_\mathsf{P}q^{\text{maj}(\mathsf{P})}=q^{k^2}\begin{bmatrix}
   n\\
   k 
   \end{bmatrix}_q^2.$$
   Here, the sum is taken over all NE-lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ with exactly $k$ peaks. I feel like this is a nice enough formula that it should be mentioned somewhere in the litterature but I have not managed to find it anywhere. Does someone know a reference for this?

Comment: 1. This is equivalent to Exercise 3 **(a)** in [UMN Fall 2018 Math 5705 midterm #3](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/18f/mt3s.pdf), since you can encode NE-paths from $\left(0,0\right)$ to $\left(n,n\right)$ as $2n$-tuples with entries in $\left\{0,1\right\}$ having exactly $n$ $1$-positions (just replacing $N$ and $E$ by $1$ and $0$, respectively).

Comment: For 1, the paths with $k$ peaks are in an one-to-one correspondence with the pairs of subsets $X, Y\subset [n]$ with $|X|=|Y|=k$. To see this, just let $X$ be the set of $x$-coordinates of the peaks in a path, $Y$ be the set of their $y$-coordinates. So, the total number of paths with $k$ peaks is $\binom{n}{k}^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula in 2 is a very special case of a result of Richard Stanley's, though it certainly could be older. (I wouldn't be surprised if it can be found in MacMahon's work.) See, e.g., my paper *[A historical survey of P-partitions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03508)*, section 7.2, for references. Just in case the connection isn't clear, your problem is equivalent to counting shuffles of the words $00\cdots 0$ and $11\cdots1$, both of length $n$, with $k$ descents, by major index. Stanley's formula counts shuffles of two arbitrary (but disjoint) permutations with a given number of descents by major index.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that you lay out the N (0) and E (1) moves as follows ($n=4$ shown):
$$0000$$
$$1111$$
As you go along the path, color $\color{red}{red}$ the ones you have used, so that after reading either 001, 010, or 100 you have:
$${\color{red}{00}}00$$
$${\color{red}1}111$$
Then you have to choose after which 0s to switch to 1s, and which 1s to switch to 0s, for a total of $\binom{n}{k}^2$ ways.